# Symfony authentication api keys lost sessions

Tags: php, api, symfony, authentication

I am following this guide http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/api_key_authentication.html to do the authentication by API KEY.

After calling the last method Authentication token I am able to login a user in, but it doesn't keep the sessions.

```
return new PreAuthenticatedToken(
        $user,
        $apiKey,
        $providerKey,
        $user->getRoles()
    );
```

I also tried to do the authentication using this following:

```
$user = new User("Test", null, array("ROLE_USER"));
$token = new UsernamePasswordToken($user, null, 'secured_area', $user->getRoles());
$this->get('security.context')->setToken($token);
$this->get('session')->set('_security_secured_area',serialize($token));
```

Both cases I am only able to log a user in for a single page, not for all project.

Security is like the guide:

```
firewalls:
    secured_area:
        pattern: ^/testproject
        stateless: true
        simple_preauth:
            authenticator: apikey_authenticator
```

Thanks

[update]

```
$user = new ApiKeyUserProvider();
$user = $user->loadUserByUsername("111111");

$apiKeyProvider = $this->get('apikey_authenticator');
$token = $apiKeyProvider->authenticateToken("111111",$user);
$this->get('security.context')->setToken($token);
$this->get('session')->set('_security_secured_area',serialize($token));
```

loadUserByUsername is like symfony guide.

Thanks

Comment: for the second method you likely need to use your token `PreAuthenticatedToken` Rather than `UsernamePasswordToken`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The authentication should happen automatically if you are following this guide correctly. All you need to do is append the parameter `apikey` to the end of your requests.

IE:

```
www.mydomain.com/testproject/get-some-random-data?apikey=vdsadbrfadbfda
```

Symfony will pick up this request in your firewall and run it through the ApiKeyAuthenticator.

If you want to keep that authentication stored in the session so that subsequent requests dont need the `apikey` then you can change the `stateless` config to false in your `security.yml`

So change:

```
firewalls:
    secured_area:
        pattern: ^/testproject
        stateless: true
        simple_preauth:
            authenticator: apikey_authenticator
```

To:

```
firewalls:
    secured_area:
        pattern: ^/testproject
        stateless: false
        simple_preauth:
            authenticator: apikey_authenticator
```

Have a look at: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/api_key_authentication.html#cookbook-security-api-key-session

Have you implemented the `refreshUser` method in your UserProvider?

```
public function refreshUser(UserInterface $user)
{
    // this is used for storing authentication in the session
    // but in this example, the token is sent in each request,
    // so authentication can be stateless. Throwing this exception
    // is proper to make things stateless
    throw new UnsupportedUserException();
}
```

Needs to become:

```
public function refreshUser(UserInterface $user)
{
    // $user is the User that you set in the token inside authenticateToken()
    // after it has been deserialized from the session

    // you might use $user to query the database for a fresh user
    // $id = $user->getId();
    // use $id to make a query

    // if you are *not* reading from a database and are just creating
    // a User object (like in this example), you can just return it
    return $user;
}
```

Comment: Where can I take this $apiKeyProvider ? Thanks

Comment: thanks! I also updated my post! I get this error: ApiKeyAuthenticator::authenticateToken() must implement interface Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface

Thanks again

Comment: Completely overhauled my answer after completely reading over the guide

Comment: If I put ?apikey=vdsadbrfadbfd i am able to login a user in but when I change page lose the sessions, in fact I got "the error token is missing". I am using that security xml. I don't want to pass the token in the url in every request . really thanks for helping me

Comment: Did you change the stateless option to false?

Comment: Did you implement the `refreshUser` method in your ApiKeyUserProvider

Comment: yes I did! can you send me the link of a ready project with authentication by API ? Thanks

Comment: I dont have one, if you have your in a github or other vcs and want i can take a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and found out that the apiKey is saved as the Token credentials. Those are erased if you don't set the following:

```
security:
    erase_credentials:    false
```